# Finding Element in Array Indicing Syntax Explanation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array in Python that looks like this:

```
array = [[UUID('0d9ba9c6-632b-4dd4-912c-e8ff0a7134f7'), array([['1', '1']], dtype='<U21')], [UUID('9cb1feb6-0ef4-4e15-9070-7735545d12c9'), array([['2', '1']], dtype='<U21')], [UUID('955d308b-3570-4166-895e-81a077e6b9f9'), array([['3', '1']], dtype='<U21')]]
```

I also have a query that looks like this:

```
query = UUID('0d9ba9c6-632b-4dd4-912c-e8ff0a7134f7')
```

I am trying to find the sub-array in the main array that contains this UUID. So, querying this would return in:

```
[UUID('0d9ba9c6-632b-4dd4-912c-e8ff0a7134f7'), array([['1', '1']], dtype='<U21')]
```

I found this syntax online to do this:

```
out = array[array[:, 0] == query]
```

I know that this only works in NumPy if the array itself is an NP array. But why does this work and how? I am extremely confused by the syntax.

Comment: `array[:.0]` returns the first column of the array.  `numpy` overrides the comparison operators (like `==`) so it can do whole array comparisons.  In this case, it will return an array of Boolean values, where each row is either `True` or `False` depending on the result of the comparison.  `numpy` also has "magic indexing", where passing an array of booleans as an index returns only those elements where the array has `True`.  It's very handy.

Comment: You can do this without `numpy` by doing `out = [a for a in array if a[0] == query]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the numpy tutorial on [indexing on ndarrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

But here are some basic explanations, understanding the examples would be a
good starting point.

So you have an array:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

The most basic indexing is with slices, as for basic lists, but you can access
nested dimensions with tuples (`arr[i1:i2, j1:j2]`) instead of chained indexing
as with basic lists (`arr[i1:i2][j1:j2]`):

```py
arr[0]  # array([1, 2, 3])
arr[:, 0]  # array([1, 4])
arr[0, 0]  # 1
```

Another way of indexing with numpy is to use boolean arrays.
You can use a tuple of lists of booleans, one list per dimension, each list
having the same size as the dimension.
And you can notice that you can use booleans on one dimension (`[False, True]`)
and slices on the other dimension (`:`):

```py
arr[[False, True], :]  # array([[4, 5, 6]])
arr[[False, True]]  # array([[4, 5, 6]])
arr[[False, True], [True, False, True]]  # array([[4, 6]])
```

You can also use a single big boolean numpy array that has the same shape as
the array you are indexing:

```py
arr[np.array([[False, True, False], [False, False, True]])]  # array([2, 6])
```

Also, otherwise elementwise operation (`+`, `/`, `%` ...) are redefined by
numpy so they can work on whole arrays at once:

```py
def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

is_even(2)  # True
is_even(arr)  # array([[False,  True, False], [True, False,  True]])
```

Here we just constructed a big boolean array, so it can be used on your original array:

```py
arr[is_even(arr)]  # array([2, 4, 6])
```

But in your case you was only indexing on the first dimension, so using the tuple of boolean lists indexing method:

```py
arr[is_even(arr[:, 0]), :]  # array([4, 5, 6])
```